# How to draw scrolling graphics in R, like financial time series

Tags: r, scroll, plot

I would like to draw financial time series in R, that are continuously updated all along the day. Sometimes I can have several updates per second and I want to draw the time series as it evolves.
Moreover, I want to improve my graphics with extra information that I will plot too on the same graph (not necessarily a time series).

So I wonder if there is either:

- a package in R to draw such series and have them scroll automatically as soon as I push new data
- or a way to do bit blit in R and simply update my graph,
- or a way to use packages like `grid` or anything else that would draw what is necessary (at least lines and points) and help scroll the data quickly to have a smooth rendering.

I would like something a bit more *modern* than a TCL/TK solution like explained [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/140731.html)

Comment: Have you looked at the `dygraphs` html widget [here](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_dygraphs.html)

Comment: What do you mean with *push new data*? You want this to work in the default R graphics devices or something different? And also, it's a good idea to post the image, or a link, to a plot similar to the one you want to create. Most people won't know what are the specifics of a financial time series.

Comment: @Molx: I took financial time series as a example and because I'm dealing with such data right now. A sound signal, or a temperature curve would be the same in fact. So imagine you have a producer sending new data points and you want to display the latest N points, and have the graph scrolls a bit everytime a new data point arrives. That's what I mean by _pushing_ new data. Maybe I was doing a reference to the fact that in a _FIFO_ queue you _push_ new data. So basically, I want to plot a FIFO vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are doing this with [shiny](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=shiny) and a timer variable which refreshes the plot every *n* seconds.

R itself isn't really made for continuous updates.  The (default) graphics device is static (so you can't easily 'append one point'), and there is only one event loop.

You can do it with external programs -- I have used both custom [Qt](http://www.qt.io) applications I wrote for this as well as custom data handler in the (awesome, under-appreciated) [kst](http://kst-plot.kde.org) real-time visualization program.

Comment: the _one event loop_ makes indeed your solution a good idea. Is it possible to ask _shiny_ to refresh on demand rather than with a timer ?I'm new to shiny, because I began to use it ... 10 seconds ago :-)

Comment: Yes, we do both.  On a time (ie unattended) as well as via a 'refresh button'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on financial data, but if the data file is itself updated along the day, the simplest solution would be something like:

```
k <- 0
while ( k<=3600 ) {
    foo <- read.table("data.txt")
    plot(foo[,1], foo[,2])
    Sys.sleep(60) # seconds
    k <- k+1
}
```

This would redraw the plot each 60 seconds. You can put a web adress for the data instead of "data.txt" also. To "scroll", you can play with the `xlim` argument to `plot()`.

Comment: My first solution was indeed to re-_plot_ like you suggested but that's unfortunately quite inefficient in my case because I can have updates several times per second.